# Under which conditions on $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ and $\rho_{12}$ the minimum variance portfolio involves no short selling?

Tags: finance, variance

If $\rho_{12} \lt 1$ or $\sigma_1 \ne \sigma_2$ then $\sigma_{V}^2$ representing the variance of the portfolio with weights $(w_1, w_2)=(s, 1-s)$ as a function of $s$ attains its minimum value at 
$$s_0=\frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}-\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho_{12}}{\sigma_{1}^{2} + \sigma_{2}^{2} - 2\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho_{12}}$$
Under which conditions on $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ and $\rho_{12}$ the minimum variance portfolio involves no short selling?

If I understand the question correctly the portfolio attains its minimum at $s_0$ so if I want to find constraints for $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ and $\rho_{12}$ that involves no short selling I have to make sure that $s_0 \gt 0$?

Comment: This question might be more suited to our [mathematical finance sister site](http://quant.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnBentin I keep trying to post on that site and they keep closing the questions stating that they are too basic and should be common knowledge

Comment: OK. Explain that in your question; but also try to rephrase your question in purely mathematical terms so that the people here can understand it. For example, replace "portfolio" by "weighted sum of random variables". "Involves no short selling" can be replaced "satisfies the constraint that $s_0\geqslant0$".